# Does tensorflow have shape variables?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tensorflow

Often, I'd like to work with variable-size data, e.g. the number of samples.

To get this data into tensorflow, I use python variables (e.g. "num_samples=2000") to define shapes.
This means I have to re-create a new graph for each number of samples.
Setting validate_shape=False is not an option to me.

Is there a Tensorflow-way of having dimension sizes as variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) allows you to create tensors which will be filled only at runtime ; and it allows to define tensors with variable-size dimensions using `None` in their shape.

[`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) gives you the dynamic size of a tensor, itself as a tensor (actually as a [`tf.TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape), which you can use e.g. to dynamically generate other tensors). See [`tf.TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape) for more detailed explanations.

An example to hopefully make things clearer:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Creating a placeholder for 3-channel images with undefined batche size, height and width:
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, None, 3))

# Dynamically obtaining the actual shape of the images:
images_shape = tf.shape(images)

# Demonstrating how this shape can be use to dynamically create other tensors:
ones = tf.ones(images_shape, dtype=images.dtype)
images_plus1 = images + ones 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(2):
        # Generating a random number of images with a random HxW:
        num_images = np.random.randint(1, 10)
        height, width = np.random.randint(10, 20), np.random.randint(10, 20)
        images_zero = np.zeros((num_images, height, width, 3), dtype=np.float32)

        # Running our TF operation, feeding the placeholder with the actual images:
        res = sess.run(images_plus1, feed_dict={images: images_zero})

        print("Shape: {} ; Pixel Val: {}".format(res.shape, res[0, 0, 0]))
# > Shape: (6, 14, 13, 3) ; Pixel Val: [1. 1. 1.]
# > Shape: (8, 11, 15, 3) ; Pixel Val: [1. 1. 1.]

# ^ As you can see, we run the same graph each time with a different number of 
# images / different shape
```

Comment: Thanks four your example. Is it possible to name a dimension?
E.g. instead of <tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 3) dtype=float32> get something like <tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(image_dim_0, image_dim_1, image_dim_2, 3) dtype=float32>?

Comment: If you want to store the dynamic value of each dimension in a variable, you can do so: `image_dim_0, image_dim_1, image_dim_2 = images_shape[0], images_shape[1], images_shape[2]`, or more concisely maybe `image_dim_0, image_dim_1, image_dim_2, _ = tf.unstack(images_shape, num=4)`.

Comment: OK, this is a nice solution. Thank you very much :)